# Native Base's Action sheet at the top

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

How to set action sheet at the top (just beneath header)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you can use the prop size to set the hight of the actionSheet. Maybe this can help!

example:

```
<Actionsheet
  isOpen={isOpen}
  onClose={onClose}
  size="full">
  <Actionsheet.Content>
    <Box w="100%" px={0} />
    {children}
  </Actionsheet.Content>
</Actionsheet>
```